# monitor cpu, gpu, memory usage in colab (pro)

Tags: google-colaboratory, wandb

I want to track the usage of the above resources while training a model with pyspark. Is there any built in method from colab, I have purchased colab pro, in order to store those numbers in a txt file? The goal is to train a model to predict these values, so we need a big amount of data, so monitoring by the graphs on the right hand side is not an option.

[image]

I have also tried using wandb, but couldn't make sense of it, so if someone has a tutorial i would be grateful.

Comment: Have you checked this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66383365/8663152? This might help you understand wandb system metrics.